# How do we calculate theta and phi in "persp(x,y,z ,theta =, phi =)"

Tags: r, data-visualization

we have `persp(x,y,z ,theta =, phi =)` , now I want to know that if I want to imagine a 3d plot from a certain angle then where should I expect the theta and phi angle. Is it something that we calculate from x axis or Y axis? Or is it a different concept.

I want to understand it in simple language. I tried reading help using ?persp in R studio but could not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Theta and phi just rotate the object. Imagine you're holding a book in your hands. Theta and phi control how the book is oriented towards your face.